# Multiple file in requestbody with openapi and openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Tags: java, spring, openapi

Originally, my method in MVC-controller with spring-boot was:

```
public Response sendMailWithAttachment(
@RequestParam(name = "wrapper") String wrapper, 
@RequestParam(name = "file", required = false) MultipartFile... file
) {...
```

**file** - vararg, multiple file request support

Now, i want to describe the specification in OAS3, and generate interface with this method:

```
  /email/sendmail:
    post:
      tags:
        - email-controller
      summary: Send email, can add attachment
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                wrapper:
                  type: string
                  description: incoming request object
                file:
                  type: array
                  items:
                    type: string
                    format: binary
                    description: file for sending (attachment)
```

but interface, after openapi-generator-maven-plugin (4.2.2) not generate vararg argument:

```
default ResponseEntity<EmailResponse> sendMailWithAttachmentUsingPOST(
@RequestParam(value="wrapper", required=false)  String wrapper, 
@Valid @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file
) {...
```

So far, I don't understand how to generate an interface with vararg or array argument support.
Thanks!!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the latest version of maven plugin (4.2.3 at the moment)
Generated interface looks good to me:

```
default ResponseEntity<EmailResponse> sendMailWithAttachmentUsingPOST(
    @ApiParam(value = "incoming request object") @RequestParam(value="wrapper", required=false)  String wrapper,
    @ApiParam(value = "") @Valid @RequestPart("file") List<MultipartFile> file
)
```